# How to use external html templates in Components with Vue.js 2.0 in Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I am using the default Laravel 5.3 setup - a fresh install with default configuration for Vue.js 2.0.

With Laravel 5.1 and Vue.js 1.x, I could easily define components like  and used `browserify` to compile.

```
Vue.component('test-component', require('./test-component');  

/*  test-component.js */
export default{
    template:require('./test-component.template.html')
}

/* test-component.template.html  */
<div class="test-component">
    <h1> Test Component <h1>
</div>
```

However, with Vue 2, the default is `webpack` (although `browserify` is also available but could not get it working and `webpack` seems better). But I am not able to get the configuration working.

I have tried various configurations, finally I have this in my gulp.js file

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2'); 

var config = {

    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js',null, null, config);
});
```

Now I am not getting any errors while compiling `gulp webpack` however when I try to view the page in the browser, it doesn't show the component and has an error/warn in the console

```
vue.js?3de6:513[Vue warn]: invalid template option:[object Object] 
(found in component <test>)

vue.js?3de6:4085Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of null(…)
```

My **app.js** main entry file (default provided by Laravel)

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('test-component', require('./components/test-component'));

const app = new Vue({
    //el: '#app',
}).$mount('#app');
```

What am I missing? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to use `html-loader` instead of `vue-loader`.

   ```
   npm install html-loader --save-dev
   ```
2. Your `gulpfile.js` (need to change the `loader`):

   ```
   const config = {
     module: {
       loaders:[{
         test: /\.html$/,
         loader: 'html'
       }]
     }
   };

   elixir((mix) => {
     mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js', null, null, config);
   });
   ```
3. Your `test-component.js` (no changes, you're good to go):

   ```
   export default {
     template: require('./test-component.template.html')
   }
   ```
4. Your `test-component-template.html`: (no changes, you're good to go)

   ```
   <div class="test-component">
     <h1>Test Component Goes Here</h1>
   </div>
   ```

**Important**

5. Here's how to define your component:

   - Using Default

     ```
     Vue.component('test-component', require('./test-component').default);
     ```
   - Or, simply use ES2015 `import`

     ```
     import TestComponent from './test-component';

     Vue.component('test-component', TestComponent);
     ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been struggling with this since 2 days. I had tried with `vue-html-loader` but didn't work. Now its working with the `import` statement but doesn't work with `Vue.component('test-component', require('./test-component').default);`. Still checking my code for any typos.

Comment: Glad to help you, Sir @Donkarnash :)

Comment: My bad, I had a typo. It works with both `import` as well as `Vue.component('test-component', require('./test-component').default);`. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that! Great! One consideration, I think using `html-loader` is a bit faster than using `vue-loader`. Because `vue-loader` will try to parse `template`, `script`, and `style` tag; while `html-loader` will only return the `html` content on your `*.template.html` file. But, still, it's all up to you, Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `gulp` file:

```
 const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
 require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

 elixir(mix => {
     mix.webpack('app.js');
 });
```

And import your components like this:

```
import Test from './Components/Test.vue';

Vue.component('test', Test);
```

Comment: This works with `.vue` files. I don't have issues with `.vue` files for components. I have issues when I have template for the component in a `html`file while the `script` for the component is in a `.js` file from where I do a `template:require('./test-component.template.html')`